# How to close a child electron window?

Tags: electron

`childWin.close()` doesn't work, because `.close()` can only work on the parent window.

I cannot use `childWin.hide()`, because I need to completely kill the child window and then create it again like it's created at initialization of the electron process. There doesn't seem to be any straightforward way of doing this.

```js
'use strict'

import electron from 'electron'
import {
  app,
  protocol,
  BrowserWindow
} from 'electron'
import {
  createProtocol
} from 'vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/lib'
import installExtension, {
  VUEJS3_DEVTOOLS
} from 'electron-devtools-installer'
const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

// Scheme must be registered before the app is ready
protocol.registerSchemesAsPrivileged([{
  scheme: 'app',
  privileges: {
    secure: true,
    standard: true
  }
}])

let win
const winWidth = 1000
const winHeight = 700
async function createWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  win = new BrowserWindow({
    width: winWidth,
    height: winHeight,
    webPreferences: {
      // webSecurity false fixes CORS issues, remove in production!
      webSecurity: false,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
      // Use pluginOptions.nodeIntegration, leave this alone
      // See nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/security.html#node-integration for more info
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false
    }
  })

  win.webContents.openDevTools({
    mode: 'docked'
  })
  win.setMenuBarVisibility(false)

  if (process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL) {
    // Load the url of the dev server if in development mode
    await win.loadURL(process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL)
    if (!process.env.IS_TEST) win.webContents.openDevTools()
  } else {
    createProtocol('app')
    // Load the index.html when not in development
    win.loadURL('app://./index.html')
  }
}

let childWin
const childWidth = 60
const childHeight = 60
async function createChildWindow() {
  // Create the browser window.
  childWin = new BrowserWindow({
    width: childWidth,
    height: childHeight,
    frame: false,
    closeable: true,
    webPreferences: {
      // webSecurity false fixes CORS issues, remove in production!
      webSecurity: false,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
      // Use pluginOptions.nodeIntegration, leave this alone
      // See nklayman.github.io/vue-cli-plugin-electron-builder/guide/security.html#node-integration for more info
      nodeIntegration: true,
      contextIsolation: false
    },
    Parent: win
  })

  const modalPath = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ?
    `${process.env.WEBPACK_DEV_SERVER_URL}/#/electronMenu` :
    `file://${__dirname}/index.html#electronMenu`

  childWin.loadURL(modalPath)
}

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
  // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  // On macOS it's common to re-create a window in the app when the
  // dock icon is clicked and there are no other windows open.
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow()
})

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on('ready', async() => {
  if (isDevelopment && !process.env.IS_TEST) {
    // Install Vue Devtools
    try {
      await installExtension(VUEJS3_DEVTOOLS)
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Vue Devtools failed to install:', e.toString())
    }
  }

  createWindow()
  createChildWindow()
})

// Exit cleanly on request from parent process in development mode.
if (isDevelopment) {
  if (process.platform === 'win32') {
    process.on('message', (data) => {
      if (data === 'graceful-exit') {
        app.quit()
      }
    })
  } else {
    process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
      app.quit()
    })
  }
}

electron.ipcMain.on('updateTileDataInElectronMenu', (event, tiles) => {
  childWin.close()
})
```

Comment: "because .close() can only work on the parent window." that's not true. `close` works on any BrowserWindow

Comment: @aabuhijleh well, when i use mainWin.close() it works fine, and when i use childWin.close() it does nothing and doesn't throw any errors

Comment: Show your code or share a minimal repo that shows how to reproduce this problem

Comment: @aabuhijleh Updated question, you can find a code example there.